# Python - Use list of points to extract data from gridded NetCDF without for loops

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

The following example uses the "Unidata" sample netCDF dataset of eastward wind which can be [downloaded from here](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3-example.nc) (2.8 MB)

I have two lists of integers that correspond to the `x` and `y` index of a gridded array in a netCDF file. I want to extract the data and save it to a 1 dimensional array or list for each of the point combinations (e.g. points: `[(x[0],y[0]), (x[1],y[1]), (x[2],y[2]), ... , (x[n],y[n])]`).

I can do this quite easily using this method...

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# grid point lists
lat = [20, 45, 56, 67, 88, 98, 115]
lon = [32, 38, 48, 58, 87, 92, 143]

# open netCDF file
nc_file = "./sresa1b_ncar_ccsm3-example.nc"
fh = Dataset(nc_file, mode='r')

# extract variable
point_list = zip(lat,lon)
ua_list = []
for i, j in point_list:
    ua_list.append(fh.variables['ua'][0,16,i,j])

print(ua_list)
```

Which returns:

`[59.29171, 17.413916, -4.4006901, -11.15424, -5.2684789, 2.1235929, -6.134573]`

However `append()` is clunky on big datasets and I'm trying to speed up my code so I also do not want to use a for loop and would rather return the results in a single line. I've tried doing so using this line:

```
# extract variable
ua_array = fh.variables['ua'][0,16,lat,lon]
print(ua_array)
```

Which returns every single possible combination of points instead of just the ones I am after:

```
[[ 59.2917099   60.3418541   61.81352234  62.66215515  60.6419754 60.00745392  52.48550797]
[ 18.80122566  17.41391563  14.83201313  12.67425823  13.99616718 14.4371767   14.12419605]
[ -5.56457043  -5.20643377  -4.40069008  -3.25902319  -2.36573601 -2.25667071  -1.0884304 ]
[-11.66207981 -11.46785831 -11.35252953 -11.15423965 -11.35271263 -11.55139542 -11.68573093]
[ -1.15064895  -1.52471519  -2.12152767  -2.67548943  -5.26847887 -5.79328251  -6.16713762]
[ -1.95770085  -0.56232995   0.82722098   1.39629912   2.65125418 2.12359285  -6.47501516]
[ -9.76508904 -10.13490105 -10.76805496 -11.31607246 -11.93865585 -11.56440639  -6.13457298]]
```

How can I slice the netCDF file so I can get the same result as the above code in a single line? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do normal indexing with `0`and `16` first, followed by advanced indexing with `lat` and `lon`:

```
ua_array = fh.variables['ua'][0,16][lat,lon]
print(ua_array)
```

Output:

```
[ 59.2917099   17.41391563  -4.40069008 -11.15423965  -5.26847887
   2.12359285  -6.13457298]
```

BTW, `ua_array` is a NumPy array. Therefore, calling its `ua_list` is bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks very much @Mike. Yes you're right, I should have referred to them as arrays. I'll edit the question for future reference. Cheers.